# Axios Mock Adapter with repeated params

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios

I am am using a mock adapter for my tests in a react app, and one of them looks like this:

`http://endpoint.com/api/entities?id=123&select=labels&select=versions&labelsLang=en`

The important part to note is that the `select` parameter is in there twice.

One of the tests is rendering in another language, so we have two mock endpoints set up to reflect this, however I cannot seem to find a way to properly mock the repeated paramter. I just keep on getting a result for the first one.

The code for the mocked endpoints is this:

```
const mockApiClient = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost" });
const mock = new MockAdapter(mockApiClient);

const params1 = new URLSearchParams();
params1.append("id", "123");
params1.append("select", "labels");
params1.append("select", "versions");
params1.set("labelsLang", "en");
mock
  .onGet("/entities", {
    asymmetricMatch: function(actual: any) {
      return actual.params.toString() === params1.toString();
    },
  })
  .reply(200, getCompanyResponse);

const params2 = new URLSearchParams();
params2.append("id", "123");
params2.append("select", "labels");
params2.append("select", "versions");
params2.set("labelsLang", "de");
mock
  .onGet("/entities", {
    asymmetricMatch: function(actual: any) {
      return actual.params.toString() === params2.toString();
    },
  })
  .reply(200, getCompanyResponseDE);
```

I know it's messy, I just want to understand how to do this properly.

Whenever I try specifying specific params in an object, it complains that you cant have a duplicate key .

(ie.
`{ params:{select:'labels', select:'versions} }`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Here's how it was done:

```js
const mockApiClient = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost" });
const mock = new MockAdapter(mockApiClient);

const params1 = {
  "id": "123",
  select: ["labels", "versions"],
  "labelsLang": "en",
};
mock
  .onGet("/entities", {
    params: {
      asymmetricMatch: function(actual: any) {
        actual.sort(); // Important, as without it the order of params would affect the result
        return actual.toString() === toURLSearchParams(params1).toString();
      },
    },
  })
  .reply(200, getCompanyResponse);


export const toURLSearchParams = (params: {[key: string]: string|string[]}, sort:boolean = true):URLSearchParams => {
  if(params instanceof URLSearchParams) return params

  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  for(const key in params){
    const value = params[key];
    if(Array.isArray(value)){
      value.forEach((eachValue) => {
        searchParams.append(key, eachValue)
      })
    } else {
      searchParams.append(key,value)
    }
  }
  if(sort) searchParams.sort() // Likewise here. 
  return searchParams;
}
```